# How do I re-gather device facts to remove any partitioned disks?

Tags: python, linux, list, loops, ansible

I'm building a role for which I'm trying to gather disks without any partitions using

```yaml
disks: "{{ ansible_devices | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'match', '^sd.*')  |  selectattr('value.partitions', 'match', '{}' )  | list  }}"
```

and then mount on the partition. But, as I'm running over a loop I wanted to update the list/disks when the mount and partition is completed.

For example, if my list at the start looks like

```yaml
disks: [sdb,sdc,sdd,sde]
```

when the partitioning and mounting on `sdb` using the `mount` module in Ansible is done, the list should be updated and look something like this

```yaml
disks: [sdc,sdd,sde]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to refresh the facts by calling the [`setup` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html) after your mounts.

So, a plain and simple task reading:

```yaml
- setup:
```

And Ansible will gather the facts of the host(s) again, so, your partition list should be up-to-date.

---

Since you cannot do it in the task itself, what you could do, in your role is to have an `include_tasks` that would make an unicity of the tasks: `parted` (or whatever you are using to partition); `mount` and `setup`.

Something like:

```yaml
- include_tasks: partition-mount-and-setup.yml
  loop: "{{ mounts }}"
```

And in *partition-mount-and-setup.yml*, something like

```yaml
- parted:
    device: "{{ item.mount_point }}"
    number: 1
    state: present
    part_end: "{{ item.size }}"

- mount:
    src: "{{ item.mount_point }}"
    path: "/mnt/{{ item.mount_point }}"
    state: mounted
    fstype: ext2

- setup:
```

*<sup>All this is untested, but you could just follow the general logic</sup>*

Comment: I tried using this but I'm running disks over a loop so how do I refresh that while in middle of a loop

Comment: You can't, this is a different task. You have to wait past your loop. What would be the purpose to refresh it in the middle of the loop either way?

Comment: @β-εηοιτ-βε, I get what you're pointing out but my requirement is that after I get the disks and after parting them when the loop runs on to the next then it should have the updated list should not contain the one already parted so like if I have 5 disks at the begining it should have only 4 the next and so on !

Comment: You simply cannot do that, that's just not how Ansible works, and since you looped on `sdb` already, that's just pointless, you know you did that item already, the loop can move on. You could alter a local variable that is a representation of that fact, but you just cannot change the fact during a loop in another unrelated task, period.

Comment: @β-εηοιτ-βε, Gotcha, but what do you think is a feasible solution to achieve the above problem using ansible?

Comment: Telling what is the reason for you wanting that list to update in the first place would be a great way to start.

Comment: @β-εηοιτ-βε, I'm trying to create a role to mount the disks attached to a VM when the mount point, size, volume group  is given as input (as list of dict's) ,so when I have 5 disks attached of same size but a different mount point I'm thinking to remove the parted disks from the ansible devices, so then I'll only have unparted disks which can be used for a different mount point

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: @β-εηοιτ-βε, The answer partly solves the problem but when I use that on a vm with 5 disks 3* 1 TB , 2* 256 GB , over ride happens how do I stop that ?